# Delete function PHP/DataBase (MVC)

Tags: php, mysql, database, model-view-controller

I can't make the delete button to work, every time I click, it doesn't work.
I used MVC
Here is all the code: https://github.com/claudiuzav/phpwebsite

**This is the function to delete the products**

```
 public function delProducts($id)
    {
        $q = "DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `ID` = ?";
        $stmt = $this->db()->prepare($q);
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**And this is where the products are displayed**

```
ublic function displayData()
    {
        $dataArray = $this->getProducts();

        $table = '';

        if (is_array($dataArray)) {
            $table .= '<table class="table table-striped">';
            $table .= '<tr>';
            // Header row
            foreach (array_keys($dataArray[0]) as $field) {
                $table .= "<th>$field</th>";
            }
            $table .= '<th>Action</th>';
            $table .= '</tr>';

            // Data rows
            foreach ($dataArray as $user) {
                $table .= '<tr>';
                foreach ($user as $field => $value) {
                    $table .= "<td>$value</td>";
                }
                $table .= '<td>' . "<a href='delete?id=" . $user['ID'] . "'>DELETE</a>";
                $table .= '</tr>';
            }
            $table .= '</table>';
        }
        return $table;
    }
```

This function are in the same file "UserModal.php"

**In another folder I have the "DeleteController.php" file with this code:**

```
class DeleteController extends AppController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->init();
    }
    public function init()
    {
        $newUser = new UsersModel();
        $id = $_GET['ID'];
        $deleted = $newUser->delProducts($id);
        if ($deleted) {
            header("Refresh: 1; url= home");
        } else {
            print_r($_GET);
            echo "ID is not set.";
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the button this error is displayed : Undefined array key "ID"

I use an **.htaccess** with this code in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)$ ?page=$1
```

And in the url is like this when I try to click the button:

```
/delete?id=15
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `$_GET['id']` over `$_GET['ID']` a try, the key will be case sensitive.

Also, it might be better to use a `$_POST` and post the data over, rather than use a GET request (you're sending data, not getting it).

Additionally, you might want to look into [UUIDs](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/dev-corner/php), as this would be more secure than sending over incrementing ID numbers which could be insecure.